# How to display the label for checked checkboxes instead of its values

Tags: javascript, php

In this code I use dropdown as an example

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-light btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="bahagian" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bahagian </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="checkboxes1" aria-labelledby="bahagian" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%;">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <input type="checkbox" name="bahagian[]" value="JB"><label>Johor Bahru</label>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <input type="checkbox" name="bahagian[]" value="TE"><label>Tebrau</label>
            </label>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
               <input type="checkbox" name="bahagian[]" value="PG"></label>Pasir Gudang</label>
            </li>         
        </div>
        
        <div id="output1" class=""></div><br>
    </button>
</div>
```

Currently this is the javascript code I used to display it values and it working but how to display the label?

```
<script>
    $("#checkboxes input").click(function () {
        $("#output").text($("#checkboxes input:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join());
    }).click().click();
</script>
```

Comment: Fix your markup... then  `$(function(){
 $('.dropdown [type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).next().text());
 });
 });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there're some errors in your code. here is what I have (https://jsfiddle.net/7a1moxqc/)

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-light btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="bahagian" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bahagian </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" id="checkboxes1" aria-labelledby="bahagian" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%;">
     <li class="dropdown-item">
       <input type="checkbox" id="jb" name="bahagian[]" value="JB"><label for="jb">Johor Bahru</label>
     </li>
     <li class="dropdown-item">
     <input type="checkbox" id="te" name="bahagian[]" value="TE"><label for="te">Tebrau</label>
     </li>
     <li class="dropdown-item">
       <input type="checkbox" id="pg" name="bahagian[]" value="PG"><label for="pg">Pasir Gudang</label>
     </li>
   </div>
   <div id="output1" class=""></div><br>
 </div>
```

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var out = $("input:checked").map(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    return $("label[for='" + id + "']").html();
  });

  $("#output1").text([...out].join(", "));
});
```